# How to look for specific ListViewItem in a ListView - C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have created ListView (C#-WPF) with three columns: Number, Action and File. First of all I'm adding several different Items to the ListView, the 'Number' is increasing with each entry added, the 'Action' is recording what exactly happened (Moved/Renamed/Removed) and the 'File' column displays for which file an action occurred.

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ActionFile" HorizontalAlignment="center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="bottom" Width="780" Margin="20,0,0,0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumberX}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Action" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActionX}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="File" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileX}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
public class FileActionEntry
{
    public int NumberX { get; set; }
    public string ActionX { get; set; }
    public string FileX { get; set; }
}
```

```
ActionFile.Items.Add(new FileActionEntry() { NumberX = numValue, ActionX = actionValue, FileX = fileValue });
```

Now, I was trying to create a foreach loop that would check whether a specific action was taken for a specific file, then to clear that entry from a ListView and return its 'Number' value. I had several different approaches but I couldn't find out how to extract a column values out of an item. I thought it could be done by using '.SubItems' but it seems that it does not work for a WPF.

Comment: I would suspect the ListView to have the `ItemsSource` property bound to a list (or rather ObservableCollection). Here you don't have that. In my sense you can easily search through a `List<FileActionEntry>` with preferably LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way of doing so is to consider binding your listView `ItemSource` to an `ObservableCollection`, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, and any update to that collection will be automatically reflected on the UI.

Consider the following example based on yours, where the entry which the fileName is provided in the `TextBox` is removed from the collection:

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Process" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ActionFile" HorizontalAlignment="center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="bottom" Width="780" Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding FileActionEntryCollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumberX}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Action" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActionX}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="File" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileX}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
 public class FileActionEntry
{
    public int NumberX { get; set; }
    public string ActionX { get; set; }
    public string FileX { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _searchText = "";
    public string SearchText
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_searchText == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _searchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<FileActionEntry> _fileActionEntryCollection = new ObservableCollection<FileActionEntry>()
    {
        new FileActionEntry(){ ActionX = "Moved", FileX = "File1", NumberX = 1},
        new FileActionEntry(){ ActionX = "Renamed", FileX = "File2", NumberX = 2},
        new FileActionEntry(){ ActionX = "Removed", FileX = "File3", NumberX = 3}
    };


    public ObservableCollection<FileActionEntry> FileActionEntryCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _fileActionEntryCollection;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_fileActionEntryCollection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _fileActionEntryCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileActionEntryCollection.Any(f => f.FileX == SearchText))
            FileActionEntryCollection.Remove(FileActionEntryCollection.First(f => f.FileX == SearchText));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should (must) use data binding ([Data Binding Overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)). This will make your life a lot easier. An essential class in the context of data binding is the [`ObservableColllection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). This collection will notify the binding target about any changes (e.g., add or remove). All `ItemsControl` like the `ListView` listen to this changes and will update their view to reflect those changes. So you *never*  need to access the control directly to add or remove items.

The view model is the binding source:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Ctor
  public ViewModel() => this.FileActionEntries = new ObservableCollection<FileActionEntry>();

  private void AddFileActionToListView()
  {
    var newFileEntry = new FileActionEntry() { NumberX = numValue, ActionX = actionValue, FileX = fileValue };

    // Add an item to the ListView
    // or any other control that binds to FileActionEntries (ObservableCollection)
    this.FileActionEntries.Add(newFileEntry);
  }

  private int CheckFileAction(string action, string file)
  {
    // Throws an exception if file not found
    FileActionEntry fileEntry = this.FileActionEntries.First(entry => entry.FileX.Equals(file, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    // TODO: Check action

    // Remove an item from the ListView
    // or any other control that binds to FileActionEntries (ObservableCollection)
    this.FileActionEntries.Remove(fileEntry);

    return fileEntry.NumberX;
  }

  private ObservableCollection<FileActionEntry> fileActionEntries;
  public ObservableCollection<FileActionEntry> FileActionEntries
  {
    get => this.fileActionEntries;
    set 
    { 
      this.fileActionEntries = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

XAML with a bound `ItemsSource`:

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <ListView x:Name="ActionFile" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding FileActionEntries}" >
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Number" Width="40" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NumberX}"/>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Action" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ActionX}"/>
          <GridViewColumn Header="File" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileX}"/>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```